# Are the verb suffixes "-ate" and "-ать" cognates?

Tags: этимология

Are the verb suffixes "-ate" in English and "-ать" in Russian cognates?

I would guess that "-ate" comes from Latin and is also the source of the verb suffix "-ar" in Spanish. Latin and Russian are supposed to be similar in many ways, so it perhaps would not be surprising.

I tried searching for this on Google but I couldn't find any results (probably because I am bad at searching). Anyway I figured that someone on this website would probably know.

Comment: Latin already had infinitives ending in `-re` (from earlier `*-se`). So the Spanish one is a different beast.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not directly cognates. The -ate comes from Latin -atus, as Roux stated above, and the -atus is dividable in -a and -tu(s), as Nikolay stated. -tus is homonymic for participle *-to and verbal noun *-tu. But the verbal noun *-tu is not the same verbal noun as verbal noun in *-ti(s), whose dative *-tei gave us our -ть- and -ти-infinitives (-чь-infinitive is -к-ть or -г-ть). The -a- of Latin verbs and of Russian verbs is usually suffix in both (and even the exception is the same: dare/дать), but it is not always the same one (though there is verbalisator -ā in both languages). So neither part is directly cognate.

I also think it is worth mentioning that when we have loanwords for verbs in -ate, they usually end in -ировать (because of German and French interference), as in castrate - кастрировать, meditate - медитировать. However, their verbal noun is -ация for -ation: castration - кастрация, meditation - медитация.

Comment: `However, their verbal noun is -ация for -ation: castration - кастрация, meditation - медитация.` maybe not always as there's a word `кастрирование` which is a genuine verbal noun, as well as `саботирование` and the like. It's true they're not completely normative or not all of them, but they're morphologically correct and used in speech

Comment: Well, the -ирование model is part of general -ние model, which is productive and correct - therefore, there is competition for two models. And, when two models compete, the more specific is to be chosen (that's why we have went not *goed and taken not *taked in English).

Comment: either `went` and `took` or `gone` and `taken` ;^)

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка All the four, actually)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, English suffix -ate [comes](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ate) from the Latin -ātus.

In Russian, there's no suffix "-ать". Usually, "-a" is considered to be one suffix, and "-ть" - another one. "-ть" [is assumed](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D1%82%D1%8C#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F) to originate from "-ти",  marker for the infinitive in proto-slavic language, which, in turn, comes from Proto-Indo-European "-tei".

So, they are quite unlikely to be cognates.

Comment: That `*-tei`, though, was the dative form of a verbal noun. And it's not a single suffix in Latin either, since there's also `-itus` (as in *preferitus*) or just `-tus` (*dictus*). I'd say, it mirrors the Russian/Slavic situation fairly well.